# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException' this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .img

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Trying to load image asynchronously I'm getting this error ***"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key img.'"*** 
My code is as below

```
 NSString *str = "URL of an image";

    NSMutableDictionary *record = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [record setObject:str forKey:@"img"];

    record = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    if ([record valueForKey:@"img"]) {
        NSLog(@"in if");
        cell.m_img.image =  [record valueForKey:@"img"];
    } else {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
             NSLog(@"in else");
            NSURL  *imageurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
            NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [record setValue:[UIImage imageWithData:image] forKey:@"img"];

                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            });
        });
    }
```

Please advise where am I getting wrong here. 
Thanks
Mayur

Comment: What happens in this line: `record = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`? At this time, the variable `record` holds a reference to some object from `_array` and you don't have any reference to your newly created `NSMutableArray` anymore.

Comment: @Theo actually i do have reference for that array..

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that you don't have a reference to your `NSMutableDictionary` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
[record valueForKey:@"img"]
```

with

```
[record objectForKey:@"img"]
```

Comment: NSDictionary supports KVC, so the suggested change is not needed.

Comment: When I did this its still crshing with this error unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe050c30'

Comment: Again replace [record setValue:[UIImage imageWithData:image] forKey:@"img"]; with [record setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:image] forKey:@"img"];

Comment: @Adithya, I don't think that's the solution. The app crashes because `record` is not a reference to a `NSMutableDictionary`. MayurCM, Try to inspect `record` either with the debugger or with `NSLog(@"%@", [record description]);`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Check if object in array is of dictionary type

  NSString *str = "URL of an image";

    NSMutableDictionary *record = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

if([[_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    record = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
      [record setObject:str forKey:@"img"];


   dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    if ([record valueForKey:@"img"]) {
        NSLog(@"in if");
        cell.m_img.image =  [record valueForKey:@"img"];
    } else {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
             NSLog(@"in else");
            NSURL  *imageurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
            NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [record setValue:[UIImage imageWithData:image] forKey:@"img"];

                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ost likeli this line

[record valueForKey:@"img"]

`objectForKey:` will return nil in the event that the key img is not set. The better choice in your case.

However, please review your code in general. You start off by creating a new `NSMutableDictionary` and assign it to `record`. Then you add a string object to that dictionary. Fine so far. 
After that you fetch an object from the array _array which you assign to `record` too. By then you do not have any reference to the newly created dicitionary any more. Is that intended. If you do not ARC then you create a memory leak here.

Edit in response to a comment below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *record = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]; // here you create a new empty instance of NSMutableDictionary and store it in record. It has a retain count of 1
[record setObject:str forKey:@"img"]; // here you add an object to that new dictionary. Now it has exactly one entry with the key "img"
record = [_array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //and here you discard the retained newly creaded dictionary by assigning another one from the array _array. What is the purpose of that?
```

Comment: YEs Actually I'm not using ARC and its referenced from above.

Comment: See my edited answer. It is not related to your original problem but you DO have a memory leak there.

Answer (score 0):

Solved The problem with the help of your comments and answer. What I did is created NSMutable Dictionary in Globally used class and initialised the variable. Thanks all for the help

```
arr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,  0ul);
    if ([[[DataManager sharedInstance] arr] objectForKey:str]) {
        NSLog(@"in if");

         [cell m_img].image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[[DataManager sharedInstance] arr] objectForKey:str]]; 
    } else {
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
             NSLog(@"in else");



                NSURL  *imageurl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
                NSData *image = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageurl];
                [[[DataManager sharedInstance] arr] setObject :image forKey:str];
                [cell m_img].image = [UIImage imageWithData:[[[DataManager sharedInstance] arr] objectForKey:str]]; 

        });
    }
```